# Como acceder al metodo setOnItemClickListener() de un ListView Kotlin?

Tags: listview, kotlin

soy nuevo en el desarrollo en android y estoy tratando de hacer una pequeña aplicación y me tope con el siguiente problema, espero puedan ayudarme:

Estoy trabajando sobre un Menu Drawer asi que en mis eventos nav_XXXX hago unas consultas PHP

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo si doy clic en nav_IniciarRuta mando a ejecutar una consulta que me envía unos datos del servidor,. Cuando los recibo los convierto en una lista y los meto en la variable datList, luego lo adapato el ListView que tengo el xml.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada nav, me da informacion diferente, pero al final termina metida en el ListView.

Ahora, mi problema es que no puedo acceder a la función setOnItemClickListener() de mi lista desde ningún lugar porque mi variable es inaccesible.
OK, mas bien no puedo usar mi lista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Hola Oscar, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Oscar acostumbra agregar siempre el texto del código en lugar de imágenes es más legible para los miembros de la comunidad, te aseguro obtendrías una respuesta más rápida, saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Esta es la declaración de tu `ListView` en el layout

```
   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListaMAIN"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
   </ListView>
```

para acceder a el método `setOnItemClickListener()` debes de obtener primeramente su referencia, esto se debe realizar tanto si usas `Java` o `Kotlin`, lo cual se realiza de esta forma:

```
  //Obtiene referencia.
  var miLista = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.ListaMAIN) as ListView
  //Asigna listener.
  miLista.setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->

            //Realiza alguna acción!

        })
```

---

#### Asignar OnItemClickListener a ListView en Kotlin.

Este es un ejemplo :

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //Obtiene referencia de ListView.
        var miLista = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.ListaMAIN) as ListView

       //Valores a agregar en ListView
        val values = arrayOf(
            "Panama",
            "Costa Rica",
            "Rumania",
            "México",
            "España",
            "Peru",
            "Ecuador",
            "Argentina")

        //Agrega valores a adapter.
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values)
        //Asigna Adapter a ListView
        miLista.adapter =adapter


        miLista.setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->

            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "You clicked my List.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        })

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]